# Problem "hiding" the <main> content behind the header

Tags: css, position, z-index, fixed

I'm not able to figure out how to "hide" the main body content behind my header on this site. It's still a work-in-progress. The header appears to be transparent, even when I set it to z-index:10 and position:fixed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://gbears96.github.io/bigStart/

Here's the code:

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #fffcf6;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*margin:0 auto;*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0px;
  border: 2px pink solid;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #002F6C;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  max-height: 5rem;
}

#spacer {
  max-height: 10rem;
  flex: 1;
}

header nav {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

header nav li {
  padding-right: 3rem;
}

header nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #002F6C;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

.mission-section {
  /*    background-image: url("../images/downtown.jpeg"); */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20rem;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #002F6C;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px pink solid;
}

.mission-section h1 {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.mission-content {
  align-items: center;
}

.features-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-left: 0.5px solid #002F6C;
  border: 2px pink solid;
}

.features-section .feature {
  display: flex;
  border-right: 0.5px solid #002F6C;
  /* padding: 0% 1%; */
}

.feature .center {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.feature h2 {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.feature h3 {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.feature .image-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.feature .content {}

.team-section {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px pink solid;
}

.images-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BigStart Company Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      <div class="header-content">
        <!-- Content: logo + nav bar on right -->
        <img src="./images/bigstart2.png" id="logo">
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Team</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="main">
      <!-- Mission Statement -->
      <div class="mission-section">
        <div class="mission-content">
          <h1 class="mission-motto">We take your company from idea to reality.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- TEMP

         <div class="temp">
             <h1> hi </h1>
         </div> -->

      <!-- Images of Features -->
      <div class="features-section">
        <div class="feature">
          <div class="center">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img src="./images/startup-square.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2>The concept.</h2>
              <h3>We take that idea...</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature">
          <div class="center">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img src="./images/metaverse.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2>The future.</h2>
              <h3>... and turn it into the next big thing.</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Team -->
      <div class="team-section">
        <div class="team-center">
          <h1> hi </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="images-container">
          <div class="image-container">
            <h2>1</h2>
            <h2>2</h2>
            <h2>3</h2>
            <h2>4</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      </main>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: In your `header-content` css add `background-color: #fffcf6;`.

Answer (score 1):

Default value of `background-color` is transparent, it just wasn't noticeable until it overlaps with other elements, you have to give it another value if you want it not to be (i.e. add `background-color: #fff` on your header). See the snippet below:

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #fffcf6;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*margin:0 auto;*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0px;
  border: 2px pink solid;
  background: #fff;
}

.header-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #002F6C;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  max-height: 5rem;
}

#spacer {
  max-height: 10rem;
  flex: 1;
}

header nav {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

header nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

header nav li {
  padding-right: 3rem;
}

header nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #002F6C;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

.mission-section {
  /*    background-image: url("../images/downtown.jpeg"); */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20rem;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #002F6C;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px pink solid;
}

.mission-section h1 {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.mission-content {
  align-items: center;
}

.features-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-left: 0.5px solid #002F6C;
  border: 2px pink solid;
}

.features-section .feature {
  display: flex;
  border-right: 0.5px solid #002F6C;
  /* padding: 0% 1%; */
}

.feature .center {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.feature h2 {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.feature h3 {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.feature .image-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.feature .content {}

.team-section {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px pink solid;
}

.images-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BigStart Company Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      <div class="header-content">
        <!-- Content: logo + nav bar on right -->
        <img src="./images/bigstart2.png" id="logo">
        <div id="spacer"></div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Team</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="main">
      <!-- Mission Statement -->
      <div class="mission-section">
        <div class="mission-content">
          <h1 class="mission-motto">We take your company from idea to reality.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- TEMP

         <div class="temp">
             <h1> hi </h1>
         </div> -->

      <!-- Images of Features -->
      <div class="features-section">
        <div class="feature">
          <div class="center">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img src="./images/startup-square.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2>The concept.</h2>
              <h3>We take that idea...</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="feature">
          <div class="center">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img src="./images/metaverse.jpeg">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
              <h2>The future.</h2>
              <h3>... and turn it into the next big thing.</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Team -->
      <div class="team-section">
        <div class="team-center">
          <h1> hi </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="images-container">
          <div class="image-container">
            <h2>1</h2>
            <h2>2</h2>
            <h2>3</h2>
            <h2>4</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      </main>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Reference from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is ***very important*** to add to @Yong's answer that `background-color` *does not inherit*. Therefore the default `background-color` value for ALL elements is transparent regardless of parent `background-color`.

So setting your HTML element `background-color` to

```
 html {
  :
  background-color: #fffcf6;
}
```

does not then set the body and all other enclosing elements to this color, they will all remain transparent.

The way to solve your problem is to change the value of the header `background-color`; as @Yong said it is defaulting to transparent when you run your code.  Giving it any other value will solve it. E.g to have it same color as the rest of the page:

```
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /*margin:0 auto;*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0px;
  border: 2px pink solid;
  background: #fffcf6;
}
```

Here are some useful references from [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp) about the background-color property.